# Disable the zoom factor on loading the Google Chart

Tags: javascript, android, google-visualization, column-chart

I am working on a project in which I want to disable or modify the zoom factor (Default zoom) on loading the google map. But I am unable to do it. When the activity starts it show following;

[image]

Code is;

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);

  var options = {
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      startup: true
    },
    height: 600,
    theme: 'material',
    title: 'Company Performance'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example: I want to fit the complete Chart in 300*300 dimensions.**

Answer (score 0):

the chart will fill the width of the container

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);

  var options = {
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      startup: true
    },
    height: 600,
    theme: 'material',
    title: 'Company Performance'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
#columnchart_material{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_material"></div>
```

Comment: are you setting a width on the container? or if the width changes, the chart will need to be re-drawn...

Comment: Width is constant. (300*300).

Comment: Is the chart drawn before the container is visible?